# SQL - get summary of differences vs previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table similar to this one:

```
| id | store | BOMdate    |
| 1  |  A    | 01/10/2018 |
| 1  |  B    | 01/10/2018 |
| 1  |  C    | 01/10/2018 |
|... |  ...  |    ...     |
| 1  |  A    | 01/11/2018 |
| 1  |  C    | 01/11/2018 |
| 1  |  D    | 01/11/2018 |
|... |  ...  |    ...     |
| 1  |  B    | 01/12/2018 |
| 1  |  C    | 01/12/2018 |
| 1  |  E    | 01/12/2018 |
```

It contains the stores that are active at BOM (beginning of month).

How do I query it to get the amount of stores that are new that month - those that where not active the previous month?

The output should be this:

```
| BOMdate    | #newstores |
| 01/10/2018 |     3      | * no stores on previous month
| 01/11/2018 |     1      | * D is the only new active store
| 01/12/2018 |     2      | * store B was not active on November, E is new
```

I now how to count the first time that each store is active (nested select, taking the MIN(BOMdate) and then counting). But I have no idea how to check each month vs its previous month.

I use SQL Server, but I am interested in the differences in other platforms if there are any.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I query it to get the amount of stores that are new that month - those that where not active the previous month?

One option uses `not exists`:

```
select bomdate, count(*) cnt_new_stores
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.store = t.store and t1.bomdate = dateadd(month, -1, t.bomdate)
)
group by bomdate
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select bomdate, count(*) cnt_new_stores
from (
    select t.*, lag(bomdate) over(partition by store order by bomdate) lag_bomdate
    from mytable t
) t
where bomdate <> dateadd(month, 1, lag_bomdate) or lag_bomdate is null
group by bomdate
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried the first one and worked like a charm. I will test the second one later.

Answer (score 1):

you can compare a date with previous month's date using [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function of TSQL.

Using NOT EXIST you can count the stores which did not appear in last month as well you can get the names in a list using [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function of TSQL introduced from SQL 2017.

```
select BOMDate, NewStoresCount=count(1),NewStores= STRING_AGG(store,',')  from 
yourtable
where not exists
(
    Select 1 from
    yourtable y where y.store=store and DATEDIFF(m,y.BOMDate,BOMDate)=1
)
group by BOMDate
```